# How to Download log files generated from log4Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, logging, log4net

I'm using log4net in a ASP.NET MVC 4 application and I'm trying to download the generated log file from log4Net.

I have in mind to download the log file with a FileResult, like:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public FileResult DownloadUserInterfaceLog()
{
    // Get the path of the log file
    string path = (LogManager.GetCurrentLoggers()[0].Logger.Repository.GetAppenders()[0] as FileAppender).File;
    // Get the file
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    string fileName = "Log.txt";
    // Return the expected file
    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
}
```

My problem is that when I call `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);`I get an Exception, cause the log file is already used by another process.

I'm already put `<lockingModel value="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" /> (which should release the file after any modification) in my Web.Config` with no success.

Begin of log4Net configuration in Web.Config:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="Appender-root" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <lockingModel value="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
        <file value="Path..." />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://blog.somecreativity.com/2008/04/04/ioexception-when-trying-to-read-a-file-using-filereadallbytes-function/) is an article about similar trouble.

> File.ReadAllBytes() function is written such that it uses a call like
>   the following to instantiate a FileStream:
>
> ```
> FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
> ```
>
> Notice that the FileShare is specified as Read. That means if you have
>   another piece of code writing to the same file at the same time, you
>   will get an error even if the other piece of code created the
>   FileStream by specifying the share mode as “ReadWrite” like so:
>
> ```
> FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite)
> ```

Solution is to write your own custom ReadAllBytes:

```
public static byte[] ReadAllBytes(String path)
{
    byte[] bytes;
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        int index = 0;
        long fileLength = fs.Length;
        if (fileLength > Int32.MaxValue)
            throw new IOException(“File too long”);
        int count = (int)fileLength;
        bytes = new byte[count];
        while (count > 0)
        {
            int n = fs.Read(bytes, index, count);
            if (n == 0)
                throw new InvalidOperationException(“End of file reached before expected”);
            index += n;
            count -= n;
        }
    }
return bytes;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to close the Appender before accessing the file:

```
((FileAppender)LogManager.GetCurrentLoggers()[0].Logger.Repository.GetAppenders()[0]).Close()
```

Comment: Seems to work ! Thank you so much !!

Do you know also, how can I restablish the log4net tracer ? (after I close the Appender)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
            var logFile = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Log.txt");
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(logFile))
            {
                var copyFile = logFile.Replace(".txt", "");
                System.IO.File.Copy(logFile, copyFile);
                var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(copyFile);
                System.IO.File.Delete(copyFile);
                return bytes;

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

However, below code can be used to open the file without throwing exception

```
using (var stream = File.Open(selectedItem.FileFullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    while (streamReader.Peek() > -1)
                    {
                        var line = streamReader.ReadLine();
                        // . . .
                    }
                }
            }
```